# Select duplicate records from another SQL select statement

Tags: sql-server, select, duplicates

```
SELECT  Field_Name ,
    type ,
    COUNT(*) AS aantal
FROM    IN_Table_Structure
GROUP BY Field_Name ,
    type
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 0 
ORDER BY Field_Name
```

Give me a result like :

Field_name ! Type  ! aantal 
..........................................
field1 ! memo ! 3 
field2 ! memo ! 1 
field2 ! arra y ! 2 

How can I create a list with only the field2 in because they have a different type for the same field?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what u want . What is the expected result set ? Try this ?

select * from 
( 
SELECT  Field_Name ,
    type ,
    COUNT(*) AS aantal
FROM    IN_Table_Structure
GROUP BY Field_Name ,
    type
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 0 
) 
A 
Where A.Type=A.Type
ORDER BY Field_Name